# Source files for the book Exploring Abstract Algebra with Mathematica

Tags: algebra, group-theory, open-source

I have been looking for the latest version from 2020.
The way back machine did not save the file.

The files that I’m looking for are :
AbstractAlgebraDownloadsV9x.zip
And Master.m

Here is the link that I have found
[wayback link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201022220904/https://sites.google.com/site/eaamhl/downloads/aapackage)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: I fixed the link for you!

Comment: It appears that Master.m is available here: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxlYWFtaGx8Z3g6ZmU1MjQyMDExZTBkYTk2

Comment: There is also this. https://extras.springer.com/1999/978-0-387-98619-7.zip

Comment: To download Master.m from above use a test editor cloud app. Because clicking on download will jot download it :)

Comment: Thank you Carl Lange, for fixing the link, Master.m is good I got it.

Comment: Thanks Валерий Заподовников for the link to the version for Mathematica 2.x ans 3.x. 
butI’m looking for the version 9.x and 10.c

Answer (score 3):

Excuse this update to the answer. You can get the files under:
https://extras.springer.com/. This link is no longer support by Springer but still exists. Use the ISBN: 9781461215301. That can be found here: [Exploring Abstract Algebra with Mathematica](https://books.google.de/books?id=2pDqBwAAQBAJ&dq=mathematica%20SubsetQ&hl=de&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Especially the links to docs.google.com and the already given extras.springer.com link do not work as expected.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Has anyone got this working on newer versions of Mathematica?

Comment: @1729taxi perhaps you can ask in chat or make a new question detailing your problems?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have found master.m (from above advice copy paste to notepad and save as master.m) follow these steps to get it working:

1. Register an account on Wolfram and get a 15 day free trial.
2. Go to online account page
   https://mathematica.wolframcloud.com/app
   and click on my files.
3. Upload master.m to cloud account
4. Open master.m within your online account
5. Install Wolfram Player (https://www.wolfram.com/player/) on your laptop and open AbstAlgebra.nb which can be downloaded at

https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4917/

6. Open a Mathematica session in your cloud account (click on Five minute hands-on session on the rhs of master.m tab in your web browser)
7. Load the package by typing the following which was copied and pasted from the AbstAlgebra notebook to the new session window command line:

   ```
          Needs["AbstractAlgebra`Master`"]
   ```

and press shift+enter

8. From Wolfram Player any command you copy will now execute correctly.
   Example: Type in the following command to see the appropriate Cayley table

   ```
    CayleyTable[Z[3],Mode->Visual]
   ```

This was the first example in the AbsAlgebra notebook to test that its working. So just copy and paste. All the other examples in the notebook will work also.
Note: You must use Wolfram Player - anything else will not allow you to copy and paste the exactly correct command and you will get formatting errors and nothing will work as I found out through trial and error.

9. All the .m files for the labs are in the zip files downloaded from the Springer link as indicated above.

Comment: Just press save on your google drive and then download master.m. But that is not whole package.

Comment: Springer link above has all the lab files in the zip files that you can download. Go through the subdirectories and you will find them. You need the Abs Algebra.nb notebook file as shown in my comment above also. If there are any problems just contact me and I can help you.

Comment: So you are saying it is all that is needed? No updates happen to other files?